# Does NHibernate session close db connection supplied as a parameter to OpenSession method

Tags: nhibernate

I wonder if Nihbernate closes db connection supplied as a parameter to `OpenSession` method.

Example

```
using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(connection))
{

}
```

I want the connection to be disposed with the session.

Best regards,
Alexey Zakharov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with customized DriverConnectionProvider

```
public class TenantConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
{
    public override IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        IDbConnection conn = Driver.CreateConnection();
        try
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = // Tenant connection string provider called here
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            conn.Dispose();
            throw;
        }

        return conn;


   }
}
```

In this case I may use OpenSession method without supplying connection string as parameter.

Comment: Hi Alexey, you didn't really answer your own question :-) "Does NHibernate close the DB connection passed to the Session constructor?" So: does it?

Comment: As far as I can tell the answer is no. That is why I'm starting to think the custom provider outlined above could be safer in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. A NHibernate session only manages the lifetime of the connection it creates; if the connection is provided from outside, it is never closed by the session, even upon `Dispose()`.